# ggplot legends - change labels, order and title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling a great deal to modify the legend in my plot. Here is a reproducible example:

```
dtt <- structure(list(model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ma", "mb", "mc"), class = "factor"), year = c(2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L), V = c(0.16, 0.14, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15, 0.16, 0.24, 0.17, 0.12, 0.13, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.16, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15), lower = c(0.11, 0.11, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.12, 0.16, 0.12, 0.04, 0.09, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.1, 0.07, 0.08, 0.05, 0.1), upper = c(0.21, 0.19, 0.17, 0.17, 0.19, 0.2, 0.29, 0.23, 0.16, 0.17, 0.16, 0.2, 0.26, 0.27, 0.15, 0.16, 0.15, 0.19)), .Names = c("model", "year", "V", "lower", "upper"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

My plot is generated like this:

```
ggplot(dtt, aes(x=year, y=V, group = model, colour = model, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.35, linetype=0)+ 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=model), size = 1.5) +       
    geom_point(aes(shape=model), fill = "white", size = 4)  +      
    theme(legend.position=c(.6,0.8)) +
    theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'grey90', size = 1, linetype='solid'))
```

which produces this:
[image]

Now, what I would like to do is

1. change the title of the legend
2. change the order in which the legend items appear
3. change the text of the legend items.

I have fiddled around for hours trying to do this, but without much success. The best I have managed so far is to add this:

```
scale_colour_hue(name = "Model 1",
    breaks=c("mb", "ma", "mc"),
    labels=c("MBB", "MAA", "MCC"))
```

But it produces this abomination:
[image]

As you see, there is now an extra unneeded legend, and the shapes in the legend do not match those in the plot !

Finally, I would like to graphics in the legend to indicate that the blue and green lines are dashed, not solid - but I have no idea at all how to do that.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Rename and re-order the factor levels before the plot
2. Rename the title of each legend to the same title

The code:

```
dtt$model <- factor(dtt$model, levels=c("mb", "ma", "mc"), labels=c("MBB", "MAA", "MCC"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dtt, aes(x=year, y=V, group = model, colour = model, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.35, linetype=0)+ 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=model), size = 1) +       
  geom_point(aes(shape=model), size=4)  +      
  theme(legend.position=c(.6,0.8)) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'grey90', size = 1, linetype='solid')) +
  scale_linetype_discrete("Model 1") +
  scale_shape_discrete("Model 1") +
  scale_colour_discrete("Model 1")
```

[image]

However, I think this is really ugly as well as difficult to interpret. It's far better to use facets:

```
ggplot(dtt, aes(x=year, y=V, group = model, colour = model, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=0.2, colour=NA)+ 
  geom_line() +       
  geom_point()  +      
  facet_wrap(~model)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful +1. I will also consider your comment about my plot being ugly. But the reason I did it that way is because I actually have more than 6 years of data so the plots will be more compressed. I did do something similar to your suggestion in the first place but my teacher said it was hard to tell to what extent the confidence bands overlap - which is part of the reason for doing this.

Comment: +1 (@ROLO your answer had a different way of reordering the factor levels and was a good alternative -- I wish you'd kept it!)

Comment: @ROLO Careful - factors don't have labels per se, the `labels` argument is used to rename the factor levels.

Comment: OK, here is another way of reordering factors: `dtt$model <- relevel(dtt$model, ref="MBB")`. This puts the factor given by `ref` at the beginning.

Comment: How can you determine `lower` and `upper` dynamically here? I think the study values are experimental defined in `dtt`. I opened a new thread about it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44167480/54964