# Sorting ggplot legends by factor (here: months)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-factor

If you consider this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(8),4,2)) 
colnames(df) <- c("x","y") 
df$dates <- as.factor(c("april", "may", "june", "august"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=dates)) + geom_point(size=3, shape=20)
```

How can I sort the legend by the temporal sequence of the months?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title)

Comment: hello. why not use the 'levels" argument of the 'factor' function? df$dates <- factor(df$dates, levels=df$dates[c(4,1,3,2)])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `df$dates<-` line with:

```
m <- c("april", "may", "june", "august")
df$dates <- factor(m, levels = m)
```

Comment: @nouse might want `ordered=TRUE` as well.