# ggplot unexpectedly sorts barcharts by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame like this

```
    OTU         DCA1.Score  ID
1   Ac1         -0.05377328 Gp01
2   Ac2          2.49918986 Gp02
3   Ac3          0.42897126 Gp04
```

and another one like this

```
    OTU     DCA1.Score      ID
1   APB_2   1.151251e+00    APB
2   APB_1   9.556547e-01    APB
3   ACT_8   -2.686852e-01   ACT
4   ACT_3   -5.396745e-01   ACT
5   VMC_1   -1.236140e-02   VMC
6   ACT_15  -3.473628e-01   ACT
7   ACT_1   -2.229005e-01   ACT
```

In both cases i use ggplot2 for a barchart

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df, aes(x=OTU,y=DCA1.Score, color=ID)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size=5))
```

In reality both dataframes have 340 rows. The first df features 21 factors in the ID column, the second one just 13.

ggplot will sort the second dataframe by factor "ID" before plotting, the first one is left untouched. Why is that?

[See the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RogTP.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title)

Comment: Or is this a more canonical answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph/5210833#5210833

Comment: Isnt the real question here why ggplot does a reorder/sorting in one case, but not in the other?

Comment: I assume that both barplots are sorted, but the first `data.frame` happens to be already in the right order. A closer look to `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` would shed light on this.

Comment: Yup, the first data.frame is indeed sorted by ID, the latter isnt. Curiously, the plots are carried out vice versa (i.e. the first df is sorted by OTU (alphabetically), while the other is sorted by ID (alphabetically) prior to the plotting.