# R - order of legend ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, stacked

I have the following data frame:

```
Author<-c("University","Office", "School","University","Office", "School","University","Office", "School")
Typ<-c("Text", "Text", "Text","Data", "Data","Data",  "List", "List", "List")
Number<-c("3","1","6","4","4","2","8","1","1")
df<-data.frame(Typ,Author,Number)
```

If I apply:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Author, y=Number, fill=Typ)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

then I get a stacked bar plot where the bars are orders in the order of the date frame, i.e. `Text`, `Data`, `List`, but the legend is in alphabethic order. Is there any (non brute force, ie. by hand) option such that I can rearrange the legend also in the "given" order of the df, i.e. in  `Text`, `Data`, `List`?

(just to clarify - I have a bunch of data frames like that which are also bigger in the sense that the vectors "Typ" (which are also different in each data frame) have more entries whose order should not be changed and also displayed in the legend. I wrote a routine which plots all these data frames so I cannot change the legends manually - I am really looking for a routine friendly solution)

Comment: The legend is not necessarily ordered alphabetically, but it's ordered by the factor levels: `df$Typ`. One way to rearrange the legend is changing the order of the factor levels, e.g. `df$Typ <- factor(df$Typ, levels = rev(levels(df$Typ)))`.

Comment: if you do not want to change directly your data, you can try ` ggplot(df, aes(x=Author,y=Number,fill=factor(Typ, levels=c('Text', 'Data', 'List'))
)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
ggplot(df, aes(x=Author,y=Number,fill=factor(Typ, levels=c('Text', 'Data', 'List'))
+ )) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers - no, my real data frame is much bigger (much more "typ"s so manual setting of the levels is unfortunately no option. Unfortunately also the first approach changes the order of typ, which is not what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title)

Comment: unfortunateyl also here I do not see how to apply this to my problem. Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could automatically set your levels according to the order how they appear in your `data.frame`:

```
df$Typ <- factor(df$Typ, levels = unique(df$Typ))
ggplot(df, aes(x=Author, y=Number, fill=Typ)) +
        geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

In this way you change the order of your `factor` according to the order in `df$Typ`:

[image]

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thanks so much!

Comment: @chris17 please mark the question as answered when you're satisfied with the given answer (you can do this by clicking the checkmark under the answer's vote counts). This stops people spending time on answering a question that has already been answered.