# Change legend labels from a ggplot object with guides?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working of from a return ggplot object and want to override the legend labels. I tried overriding with guides but it does not seem to work. Any way else to do this?

```
library ( ggplot2 ) 
    make_plot <- function (){
    g1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), fill=as.factor(cyl) )) + 
      geom_bar( ) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
    return ( g1 )
    }
    
    g1 = make_plot()

    g1 +  guides( fill = guide_legend(title.position="top"  , title ="Groups", labels=c("c","b", "c")  ) )
```

so what I want here is to have the legend labels changed to a b c instead of 4,5, 6

[image]

Comment: The labels are set via the `labels` argument of the scale so do `g1 +  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", labels=c("c","b", "c"))`. That will give a warning but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more information here [Editing legend (text) labels in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635662/editing-legend-text-labels-in-ggplot) or [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title) on changing ggplot legend labels.

But the quick answer to your question is that these could be specified in your code in scale_fill_brewer() and not guide_legend(), like this:

```r
library ( ggplot2)

g1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), fill=as.factor(cyl) )) + 
  geom_bar() 

g1 +  
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position="top", title ="Groups") ) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Edited: Updated the answer in response to your comment. It is also certainly possible to do it this way after the object is created.

Comment: thanks but the issue is that I want to change it after the ggplot object is created.

Comment: This is also possible to do after as well-- I've updated the answer.