# How to reorder items in a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am supposed to modify the default graph(named `scalesGraph001`, based on a `df` `scaled001.dat`) to graph B. I just only need to change the order and sizes of `flav`. However, I tried a lot and I failed to change the order.
The first ten rows of this `df` look like:

```
    structure(list(flav = c("c", "v", "c", "c", "v", "v", "c", "v", 
    "c", "c"), top = c("c", "s", "n", "s", "c", "c", "n", "n", "c", 
    "c"), syr = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), weight = c(13.1, 14.4, 11.4, 8.7, 6.2, 
    12.6, 5.1, 12.8, 10.9, 6.5), cal = c(1293.1, 1460.5, 1202.2, 
    844.4, 552.9, 1259.4, 520.6, 1308.1, 1084.5, 649.8)), row.names 
    = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and my codes look like

```
    p1 <- scalesGraph001 + 
    scale_size_manual(values = c('c' = 16,'s' = 12,'r' = 8, 'v' = 4)) + 
    scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c('c', 's', 'r', 'v'))
    print(p1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title)

Comment: Please provide `scalesGraph001 <- ggplot(...` creation script so that we could help

Comment: It is a homework, and the graph is already stored in the environment. I don't know how to give the creation script.

Comment: Also the professor just wants us to add codes based on the scalesGraph001... He just wants us to add codes, like scale_something_something

Comment: He also does not allow us to use factor, because we have not learnt it.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the legends are predetermined from the variable itself, so redeclare the `flav` as a `factor` and decide the order using the `levels` argument in `factor()`.

If `df` is the name of the `data.frame` and you want to arrange them in the order of *(v,c,r,s)* then you can just do:

```
df$flav=factor(df$flav,levels=c("v","c","r","s",))
```